# Angle of an inscribed quadrilateral with two opposite right angles

Tags: geometry, angle

I'm currently writing a program to track the height of the head of a 3d printer using a servo motor and a camera mounted to it.
I made a sketch in Solidworks just to visualize better the shape of the system and this is what I did.

[image] The camera "eye" is placed at the point "C", always pointing to the head "H" with the servo "S" where the rotation center is, and "B" the printer "bed".

I know the position of the printer head at each moment (BH length) , and the x and y offsets (SB, SC length respectively). What I would like to do is to compute the angle θ of the servo motor to always point to the head.

From [this](https://rechneronline.de/pi/cyclic-quadrilateral.php) website I got to this formula $\theta = \arccos\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-h^2-a^2}{2\left(xy+ha\right)}\right)$  where $x$ and $y$ are the offsets, $h$ the printed head height, and $a$ the distance between the camera and the head, and $a $is unknown. So I'm wondering how to find $\theta$ if $a$ is not known neither. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: Thank you @islamm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a=|CH|$, using the Pythagorean theorem,
$$|SH|^2=a^2+y^2=x^2+h^2\implies a^2=x^2-y^2+h^2. $$

$$\therefore\; \theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-a^2-h^2}{2(xy+ah)}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{y^2-h^2}{xy+h\sqrt{x^2-y^2+h^2}}\right)$$